# ArrayList loses data

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, baseadapter

On my app I have a `ListView` with `Checkboxes` and have an adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`to populate the `ListView`. The basic function of the list is to show debts and the user can choose which ones to pay by checking the boxes, you have the total at the bottom of the list that gets updated when the user adds/removes an item. Now, some debts are related to another and if the user checks one, any other related debt should be marked as well and same if you uncheck a debt. I also have a button that should clear all the selected debts on the list, and that's where my problem is.

I keep record of the selected debts on an `ArrayList` and it seems to work for all the program but the clear button. When the button is pressed the selected debts list seems to be always empty. Any idea on what could be happening?

Here is my adapter:

```
public class ServicesFinancialStatusAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener{

    private Context context;
    private List<Debts> debtsList;
    private List<Debts> selectedDebts;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private int tabPosition;
    private float total;
    private OnTotalChangedListener listener;

    public ServicesFinancialStatusAdapter(Context context, List<Debts> debtsList, int tabPosition) {
        this.context = context;
        this.debtsList = debtsList;
        this.tabPosition = tabPosition;
        this.total = 0;
        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        this.selectedDebts = new ArrayList<Debts>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return debtsList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return debtsList.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        ViewHolder holder;

        if (view == null) {

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_services_financial_status, viewGroup, false);

            holder.concept = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.payment_concept);
            holder.descriptionOrDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.payment_description_date);
            holder.amount = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.payment_amount);
            holder.expirationDate = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.payment_expiration_date);

            if (tabPosition > 4) {
                holder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check_box);
                holder.checkBox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);
            }

            view.setTag(holder);
        } else
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        Debts item = debtsList.get(i);

        holder.concept.setText(item.getConcept());
        holder.amount.setText(item.getAmountToString());

        if (item.isExpired())
            holder.expirationDate.setText(context.getString(R.string.expired_status_indicator));
        else
            holder.expirationDate.setText(context.getString(R.string.debts_expiration_date_indicator) + item.getExpirationDate());

        if (tabPosition < 3)
            holder.descriptionOrDate.setText(item.getDescription());
        else if (tabPosition < 5)
            holder.descriptionOrDate.setText(item.getDate());
        else {
            holder.descriptionOrDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.checkBox.setTag(i);
            holder.checkBox.setChecked(item.isSelected());
        }

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

        //Get the position of the item clicked and the data object
        Integer position = (Integer) buttonView.getTag();
        Debts item = debtsList.get(position);

        //Change the status ob the object
        item.setSelected(isChecked);

        for (Debts debts : debtsList) {

            //Check on the list for related objects and marks them as well
            if (debts.getConceptId() == item.getRelatedDebt())
                debts.setSelected(isChecked);

            //Get the amount of the debt and add/remove it from
            //the selectedDebts list and update the total
            float amount = debts.getAmount();
            if (debts.isSelected()) {
                if (!selectedDebts.contains(debts)) {

                    selectedDebts.add(debts);
                    listener.onTotalChanged(addToTotal(amount), selectedDebts);
                }
            }
            else {
                if (selectedDebts.contains(debts)) {

                    selectedDebts.remove(debts);
                    listener.onTotalChanged(removeFromTotal(amount), selectedDebts);
                }
            }
        }
        //Finally update the UI
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    //Anywhere else in the code selectedDebts has the right data but here
    //Here the size of the list is always 0
    public void unMarkDebts() {

        for (Debts debts : debtsList) {

            //Get the amount of the debt and remove it from
            //the selectedDebts list, set the data object as unselected
            //and update the total
            float amount = debts.getAmount();
            if (selectedDebts.contains(debts)) {

                debts.setSelected(false);
                selectedDebts.remove(debts);
                listener.onTotalChanged(removeFromTotal(amount), selectedDebts);
            }
        }
        //Update the UI
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    private float addToTotal(float value) {
        return total += value;
    }

    private float removeFromTotal(float value) {
        return total -=value;
    }

    public interface OnTotalChangedListener{
        public void onTotalChanged(float total, List<Debts> selectedDebts);
    }

    public void setOnTotalChangedListener(OnTotalChangedListener listener) {
        this.listener = listener;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {

        TextView concept, descriptionOrDate, amount, expirationDate;
        CheckBox checkBox;
    }
}
```

And here is my fragment code:

```
public class CheckoutFragment extends BaseFragment implements View.OnClickListener, ServicesFinancialStatusAdapter.OnTotalChangedListener {

    public static final String TAG = CheckoutFragment.class.getSimpleName();

    private List<Debts> debtsList;
    private List<Debts> selectedDebts;
    private ServicesFinancialStatusAdapter adapter;
    private TextView totalView, positiveBalanceView;
    private View noDebtsView, header, footer;
    private LinearLayout mainLayout;

    private float total, positiveBalance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);

        debtsList = new ArrayList<Debts>();
        adapter = new ServicesFinancialStatusAdapter(getActivity(), debtsList, 5);
        adapter.setOnTotalChangedListener(this);

        webServices = ((MainActivity) getActivity()).getNetworkInstance();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        //Initialize the views
        ...

        reloadData();
        onTotalChanged(0, null);

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        reloadData();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTotalChanged(float total, List<Debts> selectedDebts) {

        this.total = total == 0 ? total : total - positiveBalance;
        this.selectedDebts = selectedDebts;
        totalView.setText(getString(R.string.total_indicator) + Utilities.formatNumberAsMoney(this.total));
        getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private void reloadData() {
        debtsList.clear();
        adapter = new ServicesFinancialStatusAdapter(getActivity(), debtsList, 5);
        adapter.setOnTotalChangedListener(this);
        loadData();
    }

    private void loadData() {
        //Load debts from server
        ...
    }

    private void saveSelectedDebts() {

        for (Debts selectedDebt : selectedDebts) {
            long id = Debts.insert(getActivity(), selectedDebt);
            //Log.d(TAG, "Inserted " + selectedDebt.getConcept() + " with ID " + id);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

        if (!((MainActivity) getActivity()).drawerIsOpen) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.checkout, menu);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.clear:
                adapter.unMarkDebts();
                break;

            case R.id.checkout:
                selectPaymentMode();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void selectPaymentMode() {

        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: it's an interface to tell my main activity to update the value of total. I calculate the value of total based on the selected debts in my adapter and then send that value to the activity through that interface

Comment: If I understood well, the problem that you have is that at the function "unMarkDebts" the size of debtsList is 0 always. Is that correct? Or is the problem that listener call is not receiving the proper information?

Comment: You are correct, except that is not debtsList, it's selectedDebts the one that goes down to 0. debtsList is where I keep all the Debts objects, selectedDebts keeps record of the ones selected by the user.

Comment: I reviewed carefully your code and I think is correct. Have you check if at unMarkDebts (before the for) selectedDebts.size() is 0? If that's the case, the only option I see is that your listener is modifying selectedDebts.

Comment: Yeah I checked that too and the size remains correct until I call unMarkDebts. I can't tell what is happening that changes it

Comment: The clear button that fires the method is on the `ActionBar` so I call it from `OnOptionsItemSelected`. Could that be messing up the program?

Comment: Let's kill one by one the options. If the size of the array is 0 at the entrance of unMarkDebts and before the for, then, studying that code is no sense, the problem is not there.

Comment: So, is the arrayList different from 0 exiting onCheckedChange? Just after the notification? If so, is something in the middle, either a service in the background or the code used in OnOptionsItemSelected. Could you put that code? Probably will the kind of thing different eyes can see...

Comment: As Jack the Reaper said, let's split the problem in parts.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65778/discussion-between-carlos-j-and-trebia-project).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chat broke. I think one investigation could be:

Everytime you call reload, you are initiating from scracth the adapter with a new object, (call method new). Remove that line and just use the previous adapter (taking care of initiating the adapteer on onCreate). Notice that the vairable selectedDebts is local to the adapter and you are not passing it in the constructor.

Comment: Solved it! That part of the code was the problem! Thanks so much!